# Why do I Use white-space pre-wrap and word-space not working on the first space to set up the width of space

Tags: html, css

I use `white-space: pre-wrap` for space at the beginning of tag.
And use `word-spacing:1em` to setup the space width.

But there is a problem that the space at the beginning of the tag is not 1em width, and other spaces are all right except it.

the code:

```css
p{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-spacing:1em;
 }
```

```html
<p> This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>  This is a paragraph.</p>
```

My problem is how to change the width of space at the beginning of tag.

Answer (score 0):

The word-spacing property will only affect the space between two words, so i would add this:

```
p 
{
   padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: oh, finally i know why the space width is not right.  But the padding affect whole word in tag, i just wanna indent paragraphs(one or more) in a tag like a article. Because the data is from user input and could be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the text-indent. The text-indent CSS property sets the length of empty space (indentation) that is put before lines of text in a block.

```
p { white-space: pre-wrap; word-spacing: 1em; border: 1px solid; text-indent: 1em}
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent

Comment: thanks, but i wanna change space because there will more paragraph in a tag. Need more indent not only beginning.